# report designer in Odoo / OpenERP 8

Tags: report, openerp-7, odoo, openoffice-writer, openerp-8

I've installed Odoo 8, and now I want to create some custom Invoice templates. I can see, in OpenERP 7, we've base_report_designer which we can install on OpenERP 7, and install a relevant plugin in OpenOffice to customize the reports.

But in Odoo 8, I can not find any such base_report_designer, or any plugin. How can I create custom Invoice templates in Odoo 8?

Thanks,

Abdul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the [URL](https://github.com/odoo/odoodays-2014/blob/master/v8_reporting_engine/index.rst) which shows various way to create nv8 Style report that i.e. QWeb reprots.
Moreover the odoo8 is still backward compatible with with RML report so you can create use same plugin to create RML report on odoo8.

Comment: Thanks. But RML reports are deprecated, so don't want to use them. And also, that plugin isn't working with new OpenOffice v4.1

Comment: Well then you need to follow the URL and create report, creating report is easy as you can design it like HTML and add variable same way as possible in RML

Comment: yes, thanks. This URL https://github.com/odoo/odoodays-2014/blob/master/v8_reporting_engine/index.rst seems helpful